# How to get a HTML tag value using re

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm pulling the HTML code contained in a website using the python requests library. Then I need to get some information from these HTML codes. But somehow I didn't get that data. How do I get this data?

### HTML

```
<span data-testid="vuln-cvssv2-additional">
    Victim must voluntarily interact with attack mechanism
    <br/>
    Allows unauthorized disclosure of information
    <br/>
    Allows unauthorized modification
    <br/>
</span>
```

### Python

```
import requests
import re

link = "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-10119"
f = requests.get(link)
deneme = str(f.text)

re_base_vector = r'\<span data-testid\s*\=\s*\"vuln-cvssv2- additional"\s*\>(.*?(\n))+.*?\n\<\\span\>'
find_base_vector = re.search(re_base_vector, deneme)

print(find_base_vector)

print(find_base_vector.group(0))
```

### The output I want

```
Victim must voluntarily interact with attack mechanism. 
Allows unauthorized disclosure of information. 
Allows unauthorized modification
```

Comment: Why use regex? It is generally a bad idea with html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is generally [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6241235) with HTML. Read it in with HTML parser using BeautifulSoup then use an attribute selector:

```
soup.select_one("span[data-testid='vuln-cvssv2-additional']")
```

E.g.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<span data-testid="vuln-cvssv2-additional">
    Victim must voluntarily interact with attack mechanism
    <br/>
    Allows unauthorized disclosure of information
    <br/>
    Allows unauthorized modification
    <br/>
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
item = soup.select_one("span[data-testid='vuln-cvssv2-additional']").text
print(item)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it worked. Using BeautifulSoup for HTML is a more logical choice.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup will help you better parse and navigate through html. Simple and easy to parse a given html.

Refer:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/